# Posting job openings?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if we can use the meta section to possibly post SFDC job openings.
The organization I work for presently has a lot of openings for SFDC developers and admins. 
is it against the rules to do so?

This is one of the best gathering of good Salesforce talent so I thought it would make sense.

Would like to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Richard, are you still expecting more answers ?

Comment: I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Definitely not suited for the stackexchange format or goals of this site.** Consider that the goal of any stackexchange site is to collect knowledge in a Q&A format, where questions are specific and answers exact and not subjective or discussion prone.

All the talent that is active here, probably knows where to go when they want a new job, and is already spammed to death by recruiters.

Besides the stackexchange careers site mentioned by [Jagular](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/699/119), there are also these salesforce specific places:

- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/jobs
- [Job Postings group @ Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oZTCAY)

Answer (score 11):

Please don't encourage headhunters. I fail to see what kind of long term Creative Commons benefit a job advert would have. And what, people would vote on them? Or would you mark them as community wiki so there would be no rep gain but anybody could vandalize them?

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ could use more SF job postings ;), then there's SF's own [job bulletin board at appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?type=Job). I think it's bad enough that after agencies have saturated LinkedIn they try now to contaminate meetups and other events targeted specifically at developers.

Plus I suspect in the long run we would see more questions from job interviews popping up which for me is a shady practice at best.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect the Stack ExChange [Careers site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is the best place to take job openings.

Comment: True but isn't that for recruiters only.

Comment: It's for both job seekers and job posters.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you could buy an advertisement that would be placed here on SF.SE. There's an Advertising Info link at the bottom of the page.

That said, I wonder how people would feel about people posting info like that in Chat by leaving a comment? I'm confident there are some of us who are looking for opportunities and would appreciate being able to obtain inside info from people who already work there.

With our site being designed to preserve anonymity, its not easy to connect with someone else unless they decide to put their contact info "out there" in the text of their profile or have a web site displayed that makes them easily reachable (for some it's a large corporate site with no personal link to them); unless of course they're also well known elsewhere because of a blog, being active on LinkedIn, Github, etc.

Besides the groups others have listed, there are several SF Jobs groups and SF related groups on LinkedIn where one can post open positions. Most of those however seem to be posts submitted by recruiters.